# Iterating with Do rather than NestList

Tags: procedural-programming, iterators

This code below works fine for me.

```
factor[x_] := 
      Module[{i = 1}, 
       NestList[Module[{result}, result = #*i; i = i + 2; result] &, 1, 
        x]];
factor[10]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 3, 15, 105, 945, 10395, 135135, 2027025, 34459425, 654729075}
> ```

But I wanna get it done with `Do`.

```
fat[x_] :=    Module[{i = 1},     
  Do[
    Module[{result}, 
      result = result*i; i = i + 2; 
      result
    ],  
    {x}
  ]
]; 
fat[9]
```

I failed to pull that off. It pops up `$RecursionLimit`

Comment: At each iteration you are creating `result` again and it does not have any initial value so you are essentially doing: `ClearAll[x]; x = x + 1`

Comment: @Kuba, How can you correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way implement your function with `Do`.

```
f[n_] :=
  Module[{result = 1, list = {1}},
    Do[
      result = result*i;
      list = Join[list, {result}],
      {i, 1, 2 n, 2}];
   list]
f[5]
```

> `{1, 1, 3, 15, 105, 945}`

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as my comment in the question?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. The question doesn't have a comment made by you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant my comment on Kuba's answer.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. The two methods are similar, but since but since you posted your solution as a comment to another answer, I didn't see it. If you had written it as an answer (as I think you should have), I would likely not have posted my version.

Answer (score 3):

At each iteration you are creating result again and it does not have any initial value so you are essentially doing:

```
ClearAll[x]; x = x + 1
```

Minor issue is that you don't have to manually increment `i` but use iterator spec `{i, 1, 2 x - 1, 2}`.

Moreover, if you insist on a procedural approach you need to switch to `Table` or `Sow` from `Do` because `Do` does not return anything:

```
fat[x_] := Module[{result = 1},
  Table[   result *= i,   {i, 1, 2 x - 1, 2}  ] // Prepend[1]
]
```

Comment: Generate a symbolic continued fraction:  ```t = x; Do[t = 1/(1 + t), {5}]; t```  But this actually works!

Comment: If you have to use `Do` then: `fat[x_] := Module[{results = {1}, result = 1}, 
  Do[result = result*i; 
   AppendTo[results, result], {i, 1, 2 x - 1, 2}]; results]`
`

Comment: @kile Except that is a final fraction not each step like above.

Comment: @rohit Iterating with AppendTo will not scale well.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, thanks. I should have mentioned that. kile take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/58370)

Comment: A decent linter would catch this. :/

Comment: @Kuba, t = x; Do[t = 1/(1 + t), {#}]&/@Table[j,{j,1,5}];t

Comment: @Kuba, `g[m_] := Module[{t = x}, 
   Map[Do[t = 1/(1 + t), {#}] &, Table[j, {j, 1, m}]]; t];
g[10]`